# Tortoise SVN, Checkout sparse using "imeediate children" I'm missing overlay/externs. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been shown how to do sparse SVN checkouts in Tortoise SVN by using the checkout "immediate children including folders", then selecting the folders I want and clicking "Update to revision" this seems to do what I want.
I notice that when I do this, the "omit externals" box is checked and greyed out.

This seems to be the problem.  I need to later pick up the external overlays and can't figure out how to use "update to revision" to pick these up.
The trunk repository I work with has externs and mergeinfo externals properties.  I'm not too familiar with how overlays work. And was hoping for a quick way to pick the missing overlays on repos.

I work at a remote location and checking out full 15Gb repos takes several hours, when I only need say 100Mb of the trunk.

Is there an easy way to pick the overlays (externs and mergeinfo) up?  What section of the SVN/Tortoise documentation should I dig into to figure this out.
Thanks!